# Can I drag files from the desktop to a drop area in Firefox 3.5 and initiate an upload?

Tags: firefox, file-upload, drag-and-drop, firefox-3

I've set a ondrop event on my drop area and it receives an event when I drag an image from my desktop to the drop area.

However, according to the Recommended_Drag_Types document:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DragDrop/Recommended_Drag_Types

> A local file is dragged using the application/x-moz-file type with a data value that is an nsIFile object. Non-privileged web pages are not able to retrieve or modify data of this type.

That makes sense, but how do I prompt the user to escalate privileges to get access to the file data and send it via an `XMLHttpRequest`?

If I try it without escalating privileges when I do this code:

```
event.dataTransfer.mozSetDataAt("application/x-moz-file", file, 0);
```

Javascript returns this error:

```
Permission denied for domain.com to create wrapper for object of class UnnamedClass
```

The only article I can find on this is one from 2005 but I can't tell if the directions still apply to Firefox 3, it suggest doing this:

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');
```

which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: did you find an answer to this?? I would like to be able to at least capture the local url.  any ideas? thx man

Comment: Its possible now! See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33431704/195216

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't upgraded to 3.5 yet, you can use the [dragdropupload](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2190) extension.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm thinking of this from more of a web developer perspective, I figure most people will upgrade to Firefox v3.5 but much fewer will have this extension installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if instead of escalating privileges globally:

```
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');
    ...
    function doDrop(event) {
       ...
       var file = event.dataTransfer.mozGetDataAt("application/x-moz-file", 0);
       ...
    }
```

I escalate privileges in the function's body:

```
    ...
    function doDrop(event) {

       netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');
       ...
       var file = event.dataTransfer.mozGetDataAt("application/x-moz-file", 0);
       ...
    }
```

I get rid of the error you described and gain access to the `nsIFile` instance I was looking for.

Comment: Firefox 33 says "netscape.security.PrivilegeManager is undefined".  Looks like it was removed in FF15:  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/936845